# Static html site generating with templating

Tags: html, templates, static, static-site

Ive got to do some work on a static html site that was originally developed using dreamweaver, i want to keep the site as static html, but ideally not use dreamweaver (even though it dose have templating as the programme feels ancient compared to Sublime Text).

In the past ive experimented with Hammer app, which was great, but had some minor flaws in my opinion to do with the variables throwing an error if they weren't defined, ie. when you dont want / need to set a meta description and as far as i can tell its no longer being developed.

Are there any other ways of generating static html that allow you to use what ever editor you prefer and have templating ?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want just static (aka plain text?) file, what I do is load the original Macromedia generated file **in a browser**, then pull up the browser's Developer Tools, copy the main < HTML > tag, and paste that into whatever editor you're using now.

Comment: by static im mean just front end code html, css, and some js to animate object on page, sliders etc. By copying the Macromedia / dreamweaver html content how will i still be able to use the templating engine part of dreamweaver ?

Comment: I don't understand your 2nd question.  Your 1st question specifically states: "but ideally not use dreamweaver"

Comment: Ah ok, didnt see the question like that, I was actually posing the question as "are there any other static site templating engines", are you suggesting to open the site folder in sublime edit it and then re compile in dreamweaver is that correct ? Interesting work around.

Comment: When you say "static site templating engines" do you mean WYSIWYG editors, or what exactly?  I do all of my development in Eclipse and Notepad++, and then debug directly in the browser's Development Tools.  I don't use any WYSIWYG editors.

Comment: Im not looking for a WYSIWYG editor, just somthing that can handle templates and or variables and be compiled into a static html, css, js site for publishing. Like using `include(header.php);` and then being able to set the `<title>` by using further variables like `$title`. Similar to this - http://alt-web.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/working-with-dreamweaver-templates-dwt.html or this http://hammerformac.com/ (although both of those options have there own issues) Im looking for somthing similar. Ive also heard of building locally in php and saving with `wget` never tried it though.

Comment: OK, you should be able to use any scripting language for this then.  Perl, Phython, Php.  For example my website back in the 90s I wrote a perl script that would read in a text file, that then did regular expression parsing to replace the found tags with the correct variables.

Comment: Use something like the JSP syntax: <$=variableName%> in your "template" file, then build a regular expression that finds these tags in your template file, and then replace them with a matching variable that you have defined in your script, then just output the new html to a file, or ftp it, or whatever.